# Validating parent resources in a REST api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have the following hypothetical Uri in my Web API application:

```
/customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}
```

Calling this Uri with suitable parameters, ultimately maps an action on an OrderController, like this:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrders(Int32 customerId)
{
    // Stuff...
}
```

This action performs order related actions for that particular customer. 
In Web API, What is the best strategy for validating that the parent 'Customer' resource is valid?

I can have each of my order actions check that the customer exists, but I already have a Customer controller thats responsible for customer related actions, and knows how to handle non existent customers, so this seems like duplicated logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach this:

1. Assume the customer is valid.  This is a bad idea because someone could go straight to the order URL and bypass the customer validation logic.
2. Abstract out the customer validation logic into a utility class or business logic layer.  Then on the orders API call, validate again to make sure the customer is valid.
3. Depending on the data access layer (i.e. Entity Framework, ADO.net, etc), there is probably already a relationship between Customer and Order, so you should have a way to take the customerId provided and validate that is the correct customer for the order being requested.

Ideally, the code should validate that the customer is legitimate and that the customer is the customer that is assigned to that order.